# java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input while retrieving data

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

Getting following error while trying to get data from the table.

> java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input

The error occurs at below line:

```html
try {
   if (pgObject == null) {
   return new ObjectMapper().readValue("", Map.class); // error here
   }else {
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(pgObject.getValue(), Map.class);
   }
  } catch (IOException e) {
  // System.out.println("Exception Occured in json converter 1");
   e.printStackTrace();
   return null;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the complete stack trace. Also you need to show what is `pgObject`. SO basically you need to show some more code related to the issue

Comment: pgObject is null.

attached the complete stack trace

Comment: Ah ok, `""` will not map to Map.class. You have to use `"{}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return an empty map you have to use the below:

```
mapper.readValue("{}", Map.class);
```

Because an empty string `""` doesn't mean empty JSON. An empty JSON is indicated by `{}`. On Similar lines an empty array in JSON is indicated by `[]`